# Editing files in another user's repository without pull request?

Tags: git, github

I have two set of credentials for git: one with my work email address and one with my personal email address. I'm using Github with my personal email address, and Bitbucket when I'm working.

However, when I'm at work, I often clone a personal repository from Github, then commit and push some changes with my work ids. however I noticed that these changes were "live" on my Github page, though they were not done by "me" (since I'm using an other set of credentials), nor approved by me.

So I'm wondering: can anyone modify anyone else's repo? Shouldn't there be a pull request (as stated in this [Github doc](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-files-in-another-user-s-repository/)) or some sort of approval mechanism?
I took a look at Julian Garnier's [animejs repo](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/commits/master) for instance, and just like in my case, someone else is contributing to his commits.

So how does this work?

Comment: You must be using a valid set of credentials if you are allowed to write in your repository, only the author info differs (I guess)

Comment: [Access permissions on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/access-permissions-on-github/) both users must have write permissions. This doesn't have to be true depending on how you configure your repo

Comment: You completely confuse author/committer identification (done with username and email) and repository authentication (done with login/password or ssh key pair).